# Angular Reactive Form conditional dropdown values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have multiple dropdown fields that are dependent on each other. Also, I need to be able to duplicate the set of fields (`nested`) and for this, I am using reactive forms. The main idea is that based on the first selection, a set of values should be displayed on the next dropdown (conditional). On the first set of fields, it works just fine. When I add another unit with two fields by pushing a `FormBuilder Array` to the `FormBuilder Group`, the selection resets all fields of the same `formControlName`.

[image]

On the third block, if I select the "Outside" option, which is different from the first two blocks, it resets their values.

Below is the form definition and the getter.

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
     credentials: this.fb.array([
       this.getCreds()
     ])
   });

  getCreds() {
   return this.fb.group({
     region: ['', Validators.required],
     package: ['', Validators.required]
     });
  }
```

Is there anything I can do to keep the fields persistent? The values are stored just fine on the form. It is just a display issue.

```
    <select formControlName="region" class="form" (change)="changeRegion($event, i)" id="test-{{i}}">
      <option value="" disabled>Please select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let region of REGIONS" [value]="region">{{region}}</option>
    </select>

    <select formControlName="package" class="form"(change)="changePackage($event, i)">
      <option value="">Please choose a package</option>
      <option *ngFor="let package of PACKAGES" [value]="package.name">{{package.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You will need to provide the functions too as this seems to be a bug in the way you are updating your `FormGroup`

Comment: @OwenKelvin I already solved it. I had made a mistake by assigning the fields to a global variable. So basically the issue was not on the form, but on the approach I was following to solve it.